# Incorrect duplication?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This is my first question in this Meta, so I'm not sure of what the rules are yet in duplicating or un-duplicating questions.

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/110073/what-are-my-options-if-my-waning-company-values-me-highly) was marked duplicate of another question that it is clearly not a duplicate of. I feel like if I had removed one sentence in the linked question (which I have), the entire duplication is suddenly baseless. That is to say, they are only tangentially related at best - if even that.

How can the question be un-duplicated? What needs to be done, other than the edit I've made post-closing of the question?

Comment: With *"marked duplicate"* are you referring to that [comment](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/110073/what-are-my-options-if-my-waning-company-values-me-highly#comment340606_110073) or was it actually closed as a duplicate? I saw no indication of it being closed (and reopened) in the edit history.

Comment: @AnneDaunted Hmm. You're right. I saw a notice on the post itself along the lines of "this question may already have an answer here... This question is not a duplicate and I'll explain why." My apologies, it looks like I misunderstood the prompt for VTC as an actual close.

Answer (score 5):

If someone votes to close your question as a duplicate, you will get a notification asking you if that question solves your problem. You can then indicate that it does (which will close your question) or that it does not. If you don't believe that the question is a duplicate, it's usually worth editing your question to address why you think the two questions are not the same.

This is only one person's vote, so your question has not yet been closed. It still needs 4 more close votes to put your question on hold.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. The prompt due to a VTC had me thinking the question was *actually* closed, but in reality I should have checked the title and revision history.